# Spring Can't recognise application.proerties file. Unable to display the configuration defines in property file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, exception, spring-rest

I'm trying to display my custom message while handling the exception. But I'm getting no response in the Postman. Here is code snippet that I've used

So, Here is my controller class method

```
@GetMapping(value="/customers/{customerId}")
public ResponseEntity<Customer> getCustomerById(@PathVariable Integer customerId) throws Exception
{
    try {
    Customer customer = customerService.getCustomer(customerId);    
    ResponseEntity<Customer> response = new ResponseEntity<Customer>(customer, HttpStatus.OK);
    return response;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,environment.getProperty(e.getMessage()),e);
    }
}
```

here is my service layer method that I'm calling from getCustomerById method -

```
@Service(value = "CustomerService")
```

public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

```
@Autowired
private CustomerDao customerDao;

@Override
public Customer getCustomer(Integer customerId) throws Exception {
    Customer customer = customerDao.getCustomer(customerId);
    if (customer == null) {
        throw new Exception("Service.CUSTOMER_UNAVAILABLE");
    }
    return customer;
}
```

here is my property file

```
server.port=3557
```

Service.CUSTOMER_ALREADY_EXIST=Customer already present.Add customer with different attributes.
Service.CUSTOMER_UNAVAILABLE=Customer Details not found. Give valid customer details.

Postman response -

```
{
"timestamp": "2021-05-02T10:21:22.455+00:00",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "",
"path": "/DemoBank/customers/8"
```

}

Comment: what does missing property have to do with 500 response? 500 means internal error that happened during the server was responsing to your request. Something is throwing an exception - u just need to debug

Comment: What I want is to display my custom exception that I defined in both Service layer & property file Service.CUSTOMER_ALREADY_EXIST=Customer already present.Add customer with different attributes.  & Service.CUSTOMER_UNAVAILABLE=Customer Details not found. Give valid customer details.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you throw an exception instead of returning your custom response. Spring's exception always returns 500.

Change this line:

```
throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,environment.getProperty(e.getMessage()),e);
```

to this:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(environment.getProperty(e.getMessage()), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
```